# URL Mapping based on Resource resolver in AEM

Tags: aem

We have the following website structure:

```
content
    mysite
         en
          home
             testlevel1page
               testlevel2page
```

Now the requirement is to map:

- http://www.mysite.com/ --> /content/mysite/en/home.html
- http://www.mysite.com/testlevel1page/ --> /content/mysite/en/home/testlevel1page.html
- http://www.mysite.com/testlevel1page/testlevel2page/ --> /content/mysite/en/home/testlevel1page/testlevel2page.html

How can we achieve this through resource resolver?

Answer (score 10):

Under the `/etc/map/http` directory, add a node "www.mysite.com" and give this a `sling:internalRedirect` property of `/content/mysite/en/home`.

As per the [Sling documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html), this will "prefix the URI paths of the requests sent to this domain with the string" — i.e. in this case, appending "/content/my/en/home" after the domain name for any incoming requests to "www.mysite.com".

Optionally, if you place this under `/etc/map.publish/http`, this will only be applied to instances with a Sling run mode set to **publish**.

(As the rule is under a node called 'http', this won't be applied to secure requests. If you need to cater for 'https' too, you could copy the http node, or preferrably create a regex — this isn't as common a use case, but more info on the docs linked above.)