# Can I dynamically prefix AEM Dynamic URLs

Tags: jsp, aem

I have a project that involves a server being accessed both internally and externally but the external URL used to access the site includes a "/forms/" prefix. So my /content/* becomes /content/forms/*. The JSP's using URLs can include the prefix fairly easily but the clientLibs can't be found.

Is there a way to dynamically prefix the /etc/design/mysite/* when one is used?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What is the current path that gets formed for the clientlibraries? The usual way to URL handling is only done for `/content` while keeping `/etc/designs` consistent. What is the process around clientlib paths in your HTML source when viewed internally/externally.

Answer (score 0):

Resource mapping is what you need.  Take a look at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/resource-mapping.html

Essentially you define the mappings for different paths under /etc/map and then AEM resolves the prefixing for you.

Also see:

- [URL Mapping based on Resource resolver in AEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194654/url-mapping-based-on-resource-resolver-in-aem)
- [How to map urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456093/how-to-map-urls)
- https://cqdump.wordpress.com/tag/etcmap/