# How to create url in AEM once i created page in author view?

Tags: aem

I am reading thru AEM WCM and had a question that once after creating page in lower environments and publish where to check that look and feel? Is there any url to check? or will check in AEM only?
can anyone give example format url?

TKs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Adobe Authroing](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author.html#Concept%20of%20Authoring%20(and%20Publishing)) documentation, understand the concept and architecture of the AEM. As AEM is on the REST based concept implementation your page content path will be the page url (if you don't have any sling internal redirects or Dispatcher level url hiding implementations).

Just to explain you taking an geometrixx website OOTB example.

> Working at author end in local instance at port 4502:

Example if you have created a test page under `/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/`
the test page url will be `http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/testpage.html`

**preview mode** can be tested appending `wcmmode=disabled` at the end of your url as shown below
`http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/testpage.html?wcmmode=disabled`

> from side kick preview option

[image: preview option]

> If you have published the page (assuming your publish instance is
>   running at 4503 on local)

your page path will be `http://localhost:4503/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/testpage.html`

Comment: Thanks and as you said i am trying to understand architecture....after publishing the url's in local,we will publish to Live using Dispatcher? Or is there configuration change to check in preview and send live immediately? Please correct me if i am wrong. There is always 2 instances one in local where we see our page updates and then send Live? I am looking for some info after this local updates what happens.

Comment: Have a look at my previous answers for the below questions you will get come understanding of  AEM Dispatcher
[full example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151041/how-can-i-prevent-exposing-of-content-hiererchy-paths-within-aem-i-am-looking-f/39160609#39160609) and 
[Local AEM Dispatcher setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954232/how-to-disable-trace-requests-to-an-aem-publish-instance/38955425#38955425) 
Same can be found at my blog [aemvardhan.wordpress.com](https://aemvardhan.wordpress.com/2016/08/27/aem-dispatcher-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using touch UI then you can see the preview mode by:

Edit link: http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/testpage.html

Preview Link:
http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/testpage.html?wcmmode=disabled

- You should have a Replication Agent and configuration setup there to publish the pages. There is a default agent comes with AEM where you can publish the changes from author to publish environment.

Comment: Thanks and as you said i am trying to understand architecture....after publishing the url's in local,we will publish to Live using Dispatcher? Or is there configuration change to check in preview and send live immediately? Please correct me if i am wrong. There is always 2 instances one in local where we see our page updates and then send Live? I am looking for some info after this local updates what happens

Comment: Hi,
If you configure Dispatcher then you won't need to do anything after publish. We can also activate the pages from publish instance to any domain without Dispatcher.

For more Information you can see this
http://scottsdigitalcommunity.blogspot.ca/2015/09/september-version-of-ask-aem-community.html