# How to setup multiple domains on AEM dispatcher

Tags: apache, webserver, aem, dispatcher, vhosts

I have a website which is already hosted and using AEM. I have another domain which needs to be hosted. If it is hosted, what are the configurations that need to be configured on the same AEM system(Author, Publisher and Dispatcher).

Comment: This requires a post rather than an answer but I would recommend you to read https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-domains.html This is the simplest article to follow IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official Adobe documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-domains.html) has already been provided to you in previous posts but it doesn't come close to covering everything that is required to achieve a proper multi-tenant setup.

Unfortunately, multi-tenancy is something that can be quite difficult to get right if it hasn't been thought about right from the start and requires a highly competent team.

**Web Server**

Depending on your web server configuration, you will most likely have to add an additional [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/) entry for your new domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sitea.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/lib/apache/htdocs/content/sitea
    <Directory /usr/lib/apache/htdocs/content/sitea>
        <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
            SetHandler dispatcher-handler
            ModMimeUsePathInfo On
        </IfModule>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are rewriting requests at the web server level, you will have to add new rewrite rules by configuring [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) accordingly so that requests are forwarded to the correct content path.

**Dispatcher**

In the [dispatcher configuration](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html), you will have to create a new farm for your site based on the virtual host. I suggest you break those up into files like so:

```
/farms
{
   $include "farm-sitea.any"
   $include "farm-siteb.any"
   $include "farm-flush.any"
}
```

Note: Make sure that users cannot access restricted content of another site using your new site. For example, if `http://sitea.com/secure/page.html` should not be accessible, make sure the same goes for `http://siteb.com/secure/page.html`.

**AEM**

If you are leveraging [Sling Mappings](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html) for resolving requests coming in to your AEM instance, you will have to add additional entries for your new domain under `/etc/map`.

I've written extensively on the topic of link rewriting [here](https://shinesolutions.com/2017/01/04/demystifying-shortened-and-extension-less-urls-in-aem/).

Now that you are hosting multiple sites in a single AEM instance, you will need a *common code base* between the two applications to store instance-wide configuration and utility classes. Service configuration that you could include in this common package are:

- com.day.cq.commons.servlets.RootMappingServlet.xml
- com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker.impl.LinkCheckerImpl.xml
- com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.xml
- org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.SlingServletResolver.xml
- com.day.cq.commons.impl.ExternalizerImpl.xml
- etc

When it comes to multi-tenancy, there is a LOT to think about. Some additional areas that you may need to cover are:

- tagging taxonomy (centrally defined namespaces for content tagging)
- ACLs (site A authors should be able to author site B)
- internationalization
- workflows (OOTB workflows will impact all sites)
- DAM
- etc

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your time and answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a combination of `etc/maps` entries for your content internal redirection and the `/virtualhosts` entries to handle the content paths with the domain names, have a look at the These [how-can-i-prevent-exposing-of-content-hiererchy-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151041/how-can-i-prevent-exposing-of-content-hiererchy-paths-within-aem-i-am-looking-f/39160609#39160609) and [how-to-disable-trace-requests-to-an-aem-publish-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954232/how-to-disable-trace-requests-to-an-aem-publish-instance/38955425#38955425)

you just need to increase the `etc/map` entries with in AEM for handling content redirection with in AEM with your domain names and the respective virtual hosts entries in the dispatcher. have the documentation at my blog over [AEM-Local Dispatcher Setup & etc/maps](https://aemvardhan.wordpress.com/)